# Install unsigned driver only once, as jcoder suggested

Tags: kernel, driver

I have written a kmdf driver to activate the performance counters. I used devcon to install it after disabling driver signing during startup in Windows 10 (driver works). After restart without disabling driver signing I find "Not digitally signed" in the device manager.
See picture: [Driver not digitally signed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uguc.png)

In this post: [Entering Ring 0 with C++ using Visual Studio 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571147/entering-ring-0-with-c-using-visual-studio-15)
jcoder suggests that one could "*perhaps write a driver that enters ring 0 and then calls code passed to it. Highly insecure... but you'd only have to install the driver once.*"

I use DeviceIoControl() to enable the performance counters and read some msr registers. I don't understand jcoders suggestion. Is it something that would help me? How would I do it?